# Convex hull of a line and a circle

Tags: tikz-pic

How to draw the convex hull of a circle and a line in a grid. The picture is attached. [image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The shading?

Comment: @campa No. Shading is not that important. I do not know how to bring the graph into grid lines. Also, I do not know how to use convex hull for a circle and a line. I have just found some examples for convex hull when it is just points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is somewhat vague but here a starting point

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lightgray,step=.5](-4.5,-2.5)grid(4.5,2.5);
\draw[->](0,-3)--(0,3);
\draw[->](-5,0)--(5,0);
\draw(2,0)circle(1.5);
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{180-acos(.25)}% cos(angle) = (radius)/(distance point-centre) = (1.5)/(2-(-4)) = .25
\draw(2,0)++(\x:1.5)--(-4,0) ;
\draw(2,0)++(-\x:1.5)--(-4,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is great! Thanks.